# Unable to deploy Tyrus application on glassfish server

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, ejb-3.0, tyrus

I am trying to run tyrus websocket server through EJB on glassfish. It seems to be some kind of version conflict and bean failed to deploy. Here is exception:

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton WebSocketServerActivator
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:649)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:389)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:158)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:166)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:133)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:109)
at org.glassfish.maven.PluginUtil.doDeploy(PluginUtil.java:108)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.glassfish.maven.AbstractDeployMojo.doDeploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:259)
at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton WebSocketServerActivator
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:476)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:74)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:647)
... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:209)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2014)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:468)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at com.hospitality.sqlwebsocket.impl.WebSocketServer.initialize(WebSocketServer.java:28)
at com.hospitality.sqlwebsocket.impl.WebSocketServerActivator.startServer(WebSocketServerActivator.java:31)
at com.hospitality.sqlwebsocket.impl.WebSocketServerActivator.postConstruct(WebSocketServerActivator.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1035)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
... 82 more
```

I am using embedded-glassfish-maven-plugin to run in IDE. Tyrus maven libraries are these:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency
```

Can someone tell me which library is conflicting in glassfish.

Comment: Seems like embedded GF has already tyrus inside, but in different version and .. somehow, the code is trying to invoke non-existing method. Try mvn dependency:tree .. and also get rid of depedencies on Tyrus and depend only on javax.websocket api if possible.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. Issued is resolved now by using scope as compile in maven dependency.